# После создания Jar выходит ошибка: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx, jar

После создания jar и его запуска выходит ошибка

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3897)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1878)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2623)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:557)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:943)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1854)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mashape/unirest/http/exceptions/UnirestException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3334)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2446)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.addAccessibleMethods(FXMLLoader.java:3592)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor$1.run(FXMLLoader.java:3543)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor$1.run(FXMLLoader.java:3536)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.addAccessibleMembers(FXMLLoader.java:3535)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.getControllerMethods(FXMLLoader.java:3494)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.getControllerMethodHandle(FXMLLoader.java:573)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:781)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2924)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2639)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3331)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3287)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3255)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3227)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3203)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3196)
        at com.example.first.Controller.Translate(Controller.java:188)
        ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
        ... 80 more
```

могу предположить он не может найти бибиотеку так как в Intelij Idea всё работает.

```
public class Translate {
   public String translator(String text, String in )throws UnirestException {
       HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("https://microsoft-translator-text.p.rapidapi.com/translate?to="+in+"&api-version=3.0&profanityAction=NoAction&textType=plain")
               .header("content-type", "application/json")
               .header("x-rapidapi-host", "microsoft-translator-text.p.rapidapi.com")
               .header("x-rapidapi-key", "1234")
               .body("[\r {\r\"Text\": \""+ text +"\"\r}\r]")
               .asString();

       String we = response.getBody().replace('"', ' ');
       String[] words = we.split("text :");
       String we2 = words[1];
       String[] words2 = we2.split(", to");
       String itog = words2[0];
       return itog;
   }
}
```

а ошибку выводит ссылаясь на:

`Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("Translate.fxml")));`
иерархия файлов:

```
-src
    -main
        -java
             -com.example.first
                              Translate_Controller.java
    
        -resources
             -com.example.first
                              Translate.fxml
```

Comment: Он не может найти ваш fxml

Comment: Да, но после того как я убрал импорт оно заработало, а импорт нужен

Comment: но до сих пор не работает ((

Comment: приложите иерархию файлов

Comment: Perfect Voyage, приложил

Comment: после того как убрал импорт из  Translate_Controller то сразу всё заработало, мне кажется он не видит библиотеку

Comment: попробуйте ещё покидать Translate.fxml в разные пакеты, например рядом с классом Translate_Controller и почему кстати, вы используете Objects.requireNonNull ? А ещё, если у вас fxml лежит в ресурсах, то там по идее, даже getClass не нужен. Просто пишем имя файла в ковычках. Могу быть неправ....

Comment: да, это понятно, но после того как я убрал бибиотеку оно заработало!
но что делать с библиотекой?